# Jquery mobile $.mobile.changePage not loading scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

My problem is with Jquery mobile's changePage(), let me start out by saying i know there's a bunch of other post about this issue, but i have tried all the solutions without any luck so that's why i'm now asking for help.

I've build a Phonegap project, where each screen is = a .html file. i got my index.html that loads all the scripts needed for the entire app. Then my index.html loads a new page with $.mobile.changePage(). but when this happens the next page do'sent have any script's or css's attached to it why?

This if my index.html

```
<!--index page used to find out if the user should see the login or welcome page-->
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jqm-icon-pack-2.0-original.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Used to make sure theres as little delay on old devises as possible-->
<script src="buttonTapDelayJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="loginJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="menuJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="generalFunctionsJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javaIndex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="menuJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="generalFunctionsJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Loads the css for the menu-->
<link href="menuStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    var checkUser="admin";
    function onDeviceReady() {
        /*if the stored username is = the correctusername, it loads the welcome page if not it loads the login*/
        if(window.localStorage.getItem("user") === checkUser){
            $.mobile.changePage("welcome.html",{transition:"slide"});
            //window.open("welcome.html", "_self"); 
        } else {
            //window.open("login.html", "_self");
            $.mobile.changePage("login.html",{transition:"slide"});

        }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onDeviceReady()"> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is my login page

```
<!--Login page-->
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body onload="loadLogin();"> 
<!--Creates all content you see on the screen-->
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <div align="center" data-role="content">
        <img src="icon.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <label for="textinput">Indtast brugernavn</label>
          <input type="text" name="textinput" id="textinput" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="passwordinput">Indtast adgangskode</label>
            <input type="password" name="passwordinput" id="passwordinput" value=""  />
          </span>          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
        <div><a href="#" data-role="button" onClick="saveLogin();myFunction();">Login</a></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <div><a href="#" id="infoButton" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-theme="b" onClick="infoPopup();"></a></div>
        </div>
      </ul>         
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As stated in the start, my problem is that non of my functions on my login page works to give an example of that i got my infoButton that runs onClick="infoPopup(); and this function makes a popup navigator.notification.alert("Message", null, "Info", "OK"); But it do'sent show anything when i press it.

Am i loading my scripts wrong or whats wrong, any help would be really much appreciated?

**EDIT 1:**
If i copy all my index.html  to all other pages what happens is this. my index.html links to my login.html correct. On the login page my onClick="infoPopup(); dosent work, but my onClick="saveLogin();myFunction();" works sort of. my login info does get saved but in my saveLogin(); i got a navigator.notification.alert(); but the alert aint popping up. i know that all of my functions work because they did when i used window.open(); instead of changePage. And the reason why i changed was because with window.open(); i cant get the jquery page transitions Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
Don't really know what i did but works now:) thanks for the reply's.
Even though i tired this alrdy what worked for me was to move all javascripts and css's to the index.html.

Comment: add js code of other page inside page div `data-role=page`.

Comment: I tired linking

<script src="loginJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

loginJS contains the functions to login, as the first ting after

<div data-role="page" id="login">

But do'sent work

Comment: If i copy all my index.html <head> to all other pages what happens is this.

my index.html links to my login.html correct. On the login page my onClick="infoPopup(); dosent work, but my onClick="saveLogin();myFunction();" works sort of. my login info does get saved but in my saveLogin(); i got a navigator.notification.alert(); but the alert aint popping up.

i know that all of my functions work because they did when i used window.open(); instead of changePage. And the reason why i changed was because with window.open(); i cant get the jquery page transitions

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile does not pull the whole page into the dom, it grabs the first data-role="page" element and its descendants and pulls that into the current dom.

So any scripts in the  of the document will not be included.

I generally put all the functional JavaScript for my site on the index page and then when external pages are loaded into the dom they can benefit from the already loaded scripts.

Also, you can place JavaScript code inside the data-role="page" element and it will be included when jQuery Mobile does its AJAX load of the page.

Comment: Other way- A good system for this is to put all of your JS into an include file and include it on each page of the site. It will be ignored if pages are brought into the DOM by AJAX, but if someone refreshes somewhere in your site, the JS will be available

Comment: I tired to link all js's in my index as you can see in my code but do'sent seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the head section with all the scripts in each html page, since change page will cause reload of pages and will recreate head section.
 simple change like -

```
$.mobile.changePage("welcome.html",
  {transition:"slide"}
 );
```

Comment: I tired copying all my JS's and css's to the head of all my pages but do'sent work:(